# Partitions on a SSD + HDD setup

Tags: storage, ssd

In the next week I will get a SSD for my notebook at work. This will be my first SSD and it will have a capacity of 256GB (maybe even ~500GB). At the moment I have a 1TB HDD and ~300GB in use. I will be able to use this HDD additional to the new SSD (Lenovo ultrabay) - so storage problems can be avoided, if I only get the small SSD...

I have some virtual machines installed (but not more than two are running in the same time). I also started working with docker and created some images and containers. I hope I can replace all my vm's with docker containers in the future.

And now to my question: How would you partition the new SSD? Does it make sense to keep the home partition on HDD and the system stuff on the SSD? Of course I want to take as much speed advantages as possible. Does anyone have experiences in similar scenarios (docker, VMware)?

Does it make sense using LVM with mixed devices (SSD + HDD)?

Do I have to consider anything special when replacing a HDD with a SDD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my laptop installed **128GB SSD** and **500GB HDD** and I have `/`,  `/home` and `swap` on **SSD**, and store other files on **HDD**.

SSD:

- `/` – 20GB;
- `/home` – 100GB;
- `swap` – 8GB.

HDD:

- All 500GB on `/media/storage`.

On the **HDD** I keep only large files that don't need high-speed read/write. It's a music, videos, ISO images, system snapshots, etc. For convenience, in my home directory located symlinks to folders in the storage. They look like this:

```
ln -s media/storage/Videos ~/Videos
ln -s media/storage/Music ~/Music
```

So my laptop works quickly thanks to the system and by user configs on the **SSD**, but large files don't take up space on it and stored on the **HDD**.

I hope my experience will be useful to you.

Comment: I think that can be useful. I did not consider symlinks so far.